# PHP - Remove rss external image the size from url

Tags: php, image, url, replace

i want to remove in wordpress the image size from the url of an image who is grabbed via RSS from an external site. this images are generated random based the rss so the string must be replaced or removed auto.

the URL looks like this:

wp-content/uploads/2014/04/10154286_630741873674479_8554167680140056790_n-160x132.jpg
from the _n-160x132.jpg must be removed the -160x132 to get the full size of the image.

I have try with this but it does not works:

```
<?php 
 function remove_url_size( $content ) { 
    $content =
        preg_replace('_n[^>]*.jpg', '_n.jpg', $content);
    return $content;
} 
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_url_size' ); 
?>
```

I repeat, it will not be for only one image but unknown random images with the same method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. The only problem in your code is that you do not pass a valid regular expression pattern, it should be surrounded by `/`s

```
<?php 
 function remove_url_size( $content ) { 
    $content =
        preg_replace('/_n[^>]*.jpg/', '_n.jpg', $content);
    return $content;
} 
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_url_size' ); 
?>
```

Comment: Haha, super that works, and i have imagine that will need some slash but i haven't try. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$img_link = "wp-content/uploads/2014/04/10154286_630741873674479_8554167680140056790_n-160x132.jpg";
$new_img_link = preg_replace("/\_n[^\.]*\.jpg/", "_n.jpg", $img_link);
```

Comment: your method is only for one image. like i say in my post
"I repeat, it will not be for only one image but unknown random images with the same method."
but thanks :P

Comment: Show the case just for single, but you can swap the variable which you are using to archive the all.